# A question about HElib again

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Sorry but I've got a question about HElib again. I'm applying HElib to make a secure logical calculation and I apply bootstrapping as usual. Paras I selected was from "example". However, when I debug the program, there's a new problem:

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'helib::LogicError'  
>     what():  no key-switching matrices for k=2341, keyID=0
> ```

Is this caused by "Bootstrapping"? The methods I apply were initializing the context, make bootstrappable, and save it. After reading it, I didn't write func about boots.

Comment: My guess is that you are not generating the key-switching keys needed to bootstrap. Do you have lines like `helib::addSome1DMatrices(sk)`  and `helib::addFrbMatrices(sk)` in your code? As it is done [here](https://github.com/homenc/HElib/blob/master/tests/GTestBootstrapping.cpp#L315).

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I've done so and finished this problem. But after that, I found I couldn't save keys in files like before, did you have any idea about solutions to such problem?